# Attempting to use disconnect port object

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

In my chrome extension sometimes I have an error of "Attempting to use disconnected port object", in file : chrome/RendererExtensionBindings, in line number 159.

I checked in the chrome API and in my code base the next functions:

1. chrome.tabs.connect
2. chrome.extension.connect
3. chrome.extension.onConnect (and onConnect external)

Because I know that they are the only using the Port object.. I am using only three methods for communication in my code base:

1. chrome.tabs.onRequest
2. chrome.tabs.sendRequest
3. iframe messaging (postMessage and 'message' event listener)

In addition I don't know in which scenario it happens.. do you have suggestions? maybe I am wrong and this message can pop from chrome.tabs.onRequest/ chrome.tabs.sendRequest?

Thanks in advance, 
- Yosy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue is with the iframe messaging. More specifically you are trying to `postMessage` to an iframe/window/tab that no longer exists. Try using the [Developer Tools](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tut_debugging.html) scripts tab to pause on uncaught exceptions.

Comment: Nice one. This happened to me when I put a breakpoint on the content script that was sending the message. Debugging the content script made the popup lose focus and thus it was killed.